# MySql Сгруппировать данные с разницей во времени

Tags: mysql

Каким запросом возможно сгруппировать данные MYSQL с разницей во времени между ближайшими не более часа?

То есть, если разница во времени каждой последующей записи не более 60 минут от предыдущей, то попадает в одну группу.

Comment: А куча записей через полчаса каждая по описанной технологии ведь тоже в одну группу должны попадать, получается... вторая - в одной группе с первой, третья - в одной группе со второй, которая в одной группе с первой... и так далее.

Comment: Ну так да, так и нужно

Comment: Тогда решение видится в предварительном поиске границ диапазонов - т.е. поиске пар соседних при сортировке по времени записей, между которыми более часа. И использовании этого запроса как дополнительного источника данных с диапазонами в основном запросе для группировки по вхождению в диапазон.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select date,
       @grp:=@grp+if(date>@prev+interval 30 minute,1,0) as GRP,
       @prev:=date
  from TimeTest, (select @prev:=NULL, @grp:=1) X
 order by date
```

Дает номера групп по разнице времени, для группировки по этому полю надо обернуть его еще в один select и сгруппировать по полю GRP:

```
select ...
  from ( запрос-показанный-выше ) A
 group by GRP
```

Тест на [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09828f/8)

Comment: Да, красиво получается, спасиб!

Answer (score 0):

SELECT 
FLOOR(`time`/(60*60))*(60*60) as `t`
FROM table
GROUP BY 
`t`

Быть может так?

Comment: Если это не ответ, решающий ваш вопрос, лучше дополните сам вопрос, нажав 'Править' под ним. При наличии вашего ответа других ответов, если проблема еще не решилась, можете не дождаться (никто же на знает решен вопрос или нет). А вообще что то мне подсказывает что надо будет использовать переменные для доступа к данным из предыдущей записи, если я конечно правильно понял вопрос ...

Comment: Похоже Вы правы, а как применить такие переменные?