# Суммирование с условием

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Добрый день. Пишу SQL запрос, но не могу понять как реализовать. Есть некая база, в которой записаны ip, время и количество скачанной информации, выглядит примерно так:

```
217.182.132.29 17:12:34 22372
217.182.132.29 17:13:34 22372
217.182.132.29 17:17:34 22372
217.182.132.29 18:12:34 22372
217.182.132.29 18:15:34 22372
217.182.132.29 18:17:34 22372
```

Для этого всего я написал такой запрос, который склеивает все одинаковые ip и при этом суммирует количество скачанной информации

```
SELECT Ip, SUM(Download) as Download 
FROM requests 
GROUP BY Ip 
ORDER BY Download DESC LIMIT 0, 500
```

При этом мне надо, чтобы он суммировал количество скачанной информации в период 20 минут, т.е. должны просуммироваться первые 3 записи и последние 3 записи и на вывод получиться так

```
217.182.132.29 67116
217.182.132.29 67116
```

Пробовал разными способами, но результат один - склеивает ip, но при этом суммирует или не суммирует данные и на выводе получается так

```
217.182.132.29 134232
```

или так

```
217.182.132.29 22372
```

Вот мои попытки все это сделать, которые не увенчались успехом

```
SELECT Ip, SUM(Download) as Download 
FROM requests 
WHERE Time >= SUBDATE(Time, INTERVAL 20 MINUTE) 
GROUP BY Ip 
ORDER BY Download DESC LIMIT 0, 500

SELECT Ip, if(Time >= SUBDATE(Time, INTERVAL 20 MINUTE), SUM(Download), Download) as Download 
FROM requests 
GROUP BY Ip 
ORDER BY Download DESC LIMIT 0, 500

SELECT Ip, SUM(Download) as Download 
FROM requests 
WHERE Time BETWEEN Time AND ADDDATE(Time, INTERVAL 20 MINUTE) 
GROUP BY Ip 
ORDER BY Download DESC LIMIT 0, 500
```

База большая, поэтому и использую LIMIT 0, 500

Предложенный вариант ответа на вопрос не решает проблему, т.к. он вносит в одну группу записи несмотря на ip пользователя, а суть в том, что этот ip может быть не следующим, а вообще через 100 строк. Данное решение просто склеит 100 тысяч строк в одну

Comment: А если в "выглядит примерно так" из вопроса заменить "18:12:34" на "17:23:34", то что должно быть на выходе?

Comment: недавно был тут вопрос, там правда по неделям суммировалось, а не по 20 минут.

Comment: @Alexander Zonov по сути склеится с первыми 3. Задание вообще звучит так "Склеить количество скачанных данных у пользователя за сессию (20 минут)", т.е. так как с последнего действия не прошло 20 минут, оно туда и приклеится

Comment: @ДмитрийЧечет, если есть сессии, то должна быть и таблица сессий, в таком случае все будет намного проще.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov, так дело в том, что я сам должен сгруппировать это так, чтобы собралось только за 20 минут ближайшие это все. У меня нет данных никаких о сессиях пользователя. Все что у меня есть - находится в таблице, что я привел

Comment: Как я понял, группировать надо по признаку "Отличие от предыдущей по времени записи не более 20 минут, при этом вся группа может быть более 20 минут от начала до конца". Тогда - пронумеровать группы с использованием переменных, и по полученному номеру группы считать.

Comment: @Akina типа того получается

Comment: @Akina только все это нужно сделать одним запросом

Comment: Это и будет один запрос. С подзапросом, правда... но на этот счёт же ограничений нет?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [MySql Сгруппировать данные с разницей во времени](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/755475/mysql-%d0%a1%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8)

Comment: @Akina ограничений нет

Comment: @Mike немного не то, он сравнивает с предыдущим несмотря на разницу в ip, а запись с тем же ip может быть не следующей, а через 100 строк

Comment: @ДмитрийЧечет, так добавьте условие order во внутренний запрос - и сделайте, чтобы подряд как раз шли из одного ip.

Comment: @ДмитрийЧечет, в комментах это пытаются уточнить, но Вы как-то отвечаете вроде бы и "да", но уточняя пишете о чем-то совершенно другом. Всё-таки, вот 20 минут ограничение - если пользователь скачал в первую минуту, потом в 20ю минуту - он скачал это в пределах 20 минут, суммируем. далее он скачал в 39ю минуту - разница между 20 и 39 в пределах 20 минут, поэтому... тоже склеиваем? итог у нас получается три склеенных в одну запись? или две склеенные по две? или как вообще? Ваш пример - классический пример из ненавистных мне методичек, он показывает простейший очевидный случай. Чуть усложните его

Comment: @ДмитрийЧечет Важна же общая идея, все задачи такого рода решаются по этому пути. Остается только несколько нюансов учесть. Добавить ip первым в order by, запоминать в отдельной переменной предыдущий IP и в IF который номер группы вычисляет добавить условие `or @prev_ip!=ip`. Или даже поля и условия не добавлять, достаточно IP первым в order by поставить, а итоговую группировку делать по ip, grp

Comment: @АлександрБелинский да, должно суммироваться так, т.к. с предыдущей записи не прошло 20 минут. Тем не менее вопрос уже решил, спасибо за подсказку с order by

Comment: @Mike я примерно к этому и пришел, только вот косяк был, но после того как поменял = на !=, все сразу заработало. Спасибо!